# I think I found an important bug with UIActionSheet, did I?

Tags: ios, sdk, uiactionsheet

=== the code ===

```
UIActionSheet* as = // UIActionSheet alloc one

[as addButtonWithTitle:@"Button1"];
[as addButtonWithTitle:@"Button2"];
[as addButtonWithTitle:@"Button3"]; // this button will be set destructive
[as addButtonWithTitle:@"Button4"];

[as addButtonWithTitle:@"ButtonMore1"];
[as addButtonWithTitle:@"ButtonMore2"];
[as addButtonWithTitle:@"ButtonMore3"];

as.destructiveButtonIndex = 2;
```

=== the bug ===

my app runs in landscape mode, an actionsheet with more than 5 buttons will displayed in full-screen style, so user can scroll up and down to find a special button he want.

then the destructive button ("Button3") will be lifted to top one, I guess apple dont want people to tap a destructive button in error when scroll the actionsheet, however this make the buttonIndex and buttonTitle in wrong order :

```
NSLog(@"index = %d title = %@",buttonIndex,[actionSheet buttonTitleAtIndex:buttonIndex]);
```

the output not be exactly what they should be.
but if i not set any destructive button, then it works as expected.